# Angular 4 Drawing Routes between 2 points with API AGM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to draw Routes between 2 points with the Angle AGM API, but the dependency google.maps.DirectionsService is undefined and the injection of the maps.googleapis script is conflicting with the already implemented API, following image:

[image: IMG ERROR]

Without the google script in the index the API runs perfectly, however it lacks the google.maps dependency to instantiate in my Component.ts

```
declare var google: any;

    @Input() origin:any;
    @Input() destination:any;
    @Input() waypoints:any;

    subtitle:string;    
    constructor( 
        private costumer:ConsumerService,
        private _elem: ElementRef,
        private  _mapsWrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper,
        private loader:MapsAPILoader
    ) {
        this.subtitle = "This is some text within a card block."
    }

    lat: number = 51.678418;
    lng: number = 7.809007;

    ngOnInit(){


        this._mapsWrapper.getNativeMap().then(response => {

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
              });

              console.log(map);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            directionsDisplay.setOptions({
                polylineOptions: {
                            strokeWeight: 8,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                            strokeColor:  '#00468c' 
                        }
                });

            directionsService.route({
                    origin: { lat: '51.673858', lng:'7.815982' },
                    destination: {lat: '51.723858', lng: '7.895982'},
                    optimizeWaypoints: true,
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING'

                }, function(response, status) {

                              if (status === 'OK') {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                              } else {
                                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                              }
            });
  });
    }
```

Comment: Posting the question in english will likely get more help faster.

Comment: English please!

Comment: Leonardo, aqui o idioma padrão é o inglês. Se quiser postar em português, use o Stack Overflow em português. Leonardo, the default language here is English. If you want to post in Portuguese, use the Stack Overflow in Portuguese. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/